# How to sketch the graph of a density function in R?

Tags: r, data-visualization

Suppose I have a density function of exponential distribution  $f(x)= -\lambda e^{-\lambda x}$ where $\lambda = 0.5$.

Is there any quick command that helps drawing the graph of it, instead of manually define that function and plot it? All command I know so far is to plot the graph of a set of sample data, and I don't know how to draw the graph for the population.

Comment: Example: `curve(dexp(x, rate = 0.5), from = 0, to = 10)`

Comment: Oh thank you very much. It works! I thought "x" here must have been a data sample but now it turns out it's not necessary.

Comment: You're welcome. You can also do `curve(0.5*exp(-0.5*x), from = 0, to = 10)` and so on.

Comment: yeah that's similar to what I did before but when it comes to a little bit more complicated density functions like normal distribution's, self-defining such function consumes time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A density in R can generally be plotted exactly if the distribution is available in R using the d*** command e.g `dexp(x,rate)` or `dnorm(x,mu,sqrt(var))`. For an exponential with lambda=0.5 just use the following commands:

```
x<-seq(1,10,by=0.01) ### x-axis length
y<-dexp(x,0.5) ### exponential function for range of x
plot(x,y,type="l") ### this will plot your points as a line.
```